# JavaFX purpose of xmlns:fx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

[This Java tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) says that

> The xmlns:fx attribute is always required and specifies the fx namespace.

but what exactly is the fx namespace? 
And what values qualify for this attribute?